# Return part of string in text file

Tags: text-processing

**Background:**

All logs go to csv for mysql import.

Have a great many logs with data like:

```
Moon,Srv-1,2016-04-04 06:59:48,Entry #103 (s) test (AlphaNum_Need_This_32_Char_Long1),Msg On (ref2357 : Act)
Moon,Srv-2,2016-03-04 06:59:48,Entry #2  SomeLongtest (AlphaNum_Need_This_32_Char_Long2),Msg On (ref2357 : Act)
```

**Problem:**

1. How to extract:

   ```
   AlphaNum_Need_This_32_Char_Long1
   AlphaNum_Need_This_32_Char_Long2
   ```

or

2. Discard the part `Entry #103 (s) test`.

   => The issue, this text can vary a lot in length and chars with alpha, num, `( { } [ ] ( ) / \ . < ># @ _ -`

**Current progress:**

- Can extract all other fields with `sed` and `awk`.
- In Excel this would solve the issue {where text is D4}:

  ```
  =MID(D4,SEARCH("),",D4)-32,32)
  ```

Used MS Logparser till now, reversed the string, search count the 32 chars etc.

**Goal:** Do not use Windows logparser, do all in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r 's/^.*\((.{32})\).*$/\1/' filename
```

Comment: Possible future readers.
Solved the example.
Credit to a great many tutorials and help text online.

awk -F"," 'BEGIN{OFS=",";} { print $1, $2, $3, substr($4,length($4)-32,32), $5, $6;}' "$varFile".txt >> Some_TextFile.txt

Answer (score 0):

In Perl, you can count characters from the right if you use a negative index:

```
perl -aF, -lne 'print substr $F[3], -33, 32' < input
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-a` splits the input into the `@F` array
- `-F` specifies on what to split
- `-l` adds newlines to prints

Comment: Thank you.

Will try the Perl later. 
Using the sed for now.